# How can I detect mouse events on sprites in a canvas?

Tags: javascript, html-canvas, events, mouse

I'm making an HTML 5 game. I want mouse clicks on sprites drawn in a canvas element cause events that my code can react to. At the moment, I'm doing it by checking through all of my sprites in a for-loop on each click.

Is there a way to do that by adding an event listener to a sprite so it would respond just like that?

Are Javascript's custom events useful in this situation? I know it's possible with KinectJS, but I don't have any experience with it and really I'd like to learn how to do this myself without the help of a library.

Answer (score 4):

The computer graphics term for what you're trying to do is **picking**.

The issue with picking from an HTML `canvas` is that the `canvas` doesn't understand anything about sprites -- all it knows about is pixels. In more general terms, `canvas` is a purely graphical representation -- it stores no semantic information. It has no idea what you wanted those pixels to represent.

The *sprites* you're talking about (which  you're `for`-looping over and which KineticJS has triggering events and such) are not defined at the `canvas` level, but at your application's level. You could be rendering them with WebGL or SVG or anything else, but their semantics (what they *mean*) would stay the same. *That*'s where you should be asking *what did we click on?*

All of this is just a long way of saying **you're doing it totally right**. :) Looping over objects to see which one of them was clicked is totally reasonable. (The `canvas` could only have told you is what colour the clicked pixel was.)

---

Some stuff you might want to consider:

- If you want pixel-perfect picking from a `canvas`, there's a very good discussion of that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578545/pixel-perfect-2d-mouse-picking-with-canvas).
- If you're worried about picking performance as the number of objects increases, you could speed it up by storing your objects in a [quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree). I've had great success using [D3](http://d3js.org/)'s [quadtree implementation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quadtree-Geom).
- If you want to make your own `EventEmitter`s, consider using [Node.js' event API](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html), which has been [ported](https://github.com/Gozala/events) to also run on browser JS engines.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That makes complete sense really. Good thing is i don't have too much object/sprite at the moment (Max 30 to 40 at times) . I will look into pixel perfect picking more. Thanks again.

Comment: @aaa No problem, it's a learning resource for future readers too. I added a few more helpful links and a little about event emitters.