# Clicking on a canvas getting polygon

Tags: html5, html-canvas

I'm using Canvas to create polygons like this:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6675193

I want each of those polygons to represent a clickable province. How do I know which province is clicked when the user clicks on something? I have a list of vertices (thousands) but I feel like each time looking for the closest vertex is too slow (I think I might be wrong). What's a fast way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: I answered a very similar question [How can I detect mouse events on sprites in a canvas?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/68890/how-can-i-detect-mouse-events-on-sprites-in-a-canvas) just yesterday. Is it helpful?

Comment: By the way, if you're using D3 already, [d3.geom.quadtree](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quadtree-Geom) is perfect for minimising the cost of looking through thousands of vertices to find the nearest one. [Here's a nice example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4343214) of how to use it.